# How to merge two DataFrames in the following way?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas DataFrame.

`df1` looks like this:

```
Date        A   B
2020-03-01  12  15
2020-03-02  13  16
2020-03-03  14  17
```

while `df2`, like this:

```
Date        C
2020-03-03  x
2020-03-01  w
2020-03-05  y
```

I want to merge `df2` to `df1` such that the values turn into columns. Kinda like a one-hot encoding:

```
Date        A   B   w  x  y  z
2020-03-01  12  15  1  0  0  0
2020-03-02  13  16  0  0  0  1
2020-03-03  14  17  0  1  0  0
```

So the first row has a 1 in column `w` because the row with the same date, "2020-03-01", in `df2['C']` is "w". Column `z` is for those entries in `df1` without corresponding dates in `df2`. (Sorry if I couldn't explain it better. Feel free to clarify.)

As a solution, I thought of merging `df1` and `df2` first, like this:

```
Date        A   B   C
2020-03-01  12  15  w
2020-03-02  13  16  -
2020-03-03  14  17  x
```

Then doing one-hot encoding using:

```
df1['w'] = (df2['C'] == 'w')*1.0
df1['y'] = (df2['C'] == 'y')*1.0
...
```

But I'm still thinking of how to code the first part, and the whole solution may not even be efficient. So I'm asking in case you know a more efficient way, like some combination of DataFrame methods. Thank you.

Comment: how do you get z?

Comment: @anky_91, if the date in `df1` has no matching date in `df2` (like 2020-03-02), it will be a 1 in column `z` (like an `others` column)

Answer (score 3):

You can do with `get_dummies` and `reindex` to get `z` values:

```
df1.merge(pd.get_dummies(df2['C'])
            .reindex(list('wxyz'), axis=1, fill_value=0)
            .assign(Date=df2.Date),
          on='Date',    
          how='left'
         ).fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
         Date   A   B    w    x    y    z
0  2020-03-01  12  15  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  2020-03-02  13  16  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2  2020-03-03  14  17  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first build a `tmp` dataframe by using `get_dummies` after merging df1 and df2 on `Date`. Use `reindex` to make sure to have all columns, eventually filled with 0:

```
tmp = pd.get_dummies(df1.merge(df2, 'left', on='Date')['C']).reindex(df2['C'].values,
                                                                      axis=1, fill_value=0)
```

it gives:

```
   x  w  y
0  0  1  0
1  0  0  0
2  1  0  0
```

We can now compute the `z` column to be 1 if no 1 is present on the row and concat to `df1`:

```
tmp['z'] = 1 - tmp.aggregate('sum', axis=1)
resul = pd.concat([df1, tmp], axis=1)
```

to obtain:

```
         Date   A   B  x  w  y  z
0  2020-03-01  12  15  0  1  0  0
1  2020-03-02  13  16  0  0  0  1
2  2020-03-03  14  17  1  0  0  0
```